# Qliksense; dynamic dimensions for table

Tags: data-science, business-intelligence, qliksense

I'm trying to create a "dynamic" dimensions for a table in Qliksense. In Qlikview, I was able to do this by creating buttons that assign a value(field) to a variable, and then simply use the variable as the dimension in the table. This does not seem to work in Qliksense. As an example: I am trying to create a table that shows the total sales volume, number of transactions, average order value and conversion. I want to be able to toggle between the dimensions merchant country, consumer country and merchant. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

It should be the same approach as QlikView.

(Using QS June 2020 version)

- created a variable called `vDimension`
- created 2 buttons

  - button 1's action is to `Set variable value` (`vDimension`) to `[My Field]`
  - button 2's action is to `Set variable value` to `[My other Field]`
- created a table and for the dimension added `=$(vDimension)` (and whatever measures)

With this setup whenever one of the buttons is pressed the table's dimension is changed as well

Comment: Thanks! It did not work for me the way you describe. However, I did find a way to make it work. I first created an inline table(Dim) with the fields I wanted to use as dimensions. Then created a variable with: 
`if(GetFieldSelections(Dim) = 'merchant',
if(GetFieldSelections(Dim) = 'country'))....` etc. Then used the extension variable input to have buttons for each dimension. Then, as you suggested and as in QV, just used the variable as the dimension in the table. To be honest, I'm not entirely sure why your suggestion did not work.

Comment: its odd indeed. Might a version issue (either qlik or the extension). Its nice that you've made it working!